Why does adding an empty columnstore index to my tables consistently make execution plans ignore bitmaps?
Problem
I am using a Standard Edition SQL Server 2019 box. Given the edition, compatibility levels should not be relevant (the level-dependent batch mode features are disallowed on Standard). On this box, I have been experimenting with the hack of adding an empty non-clustered filtered columnstore index to a temp table before joining it on to other tables, thus allowing the queries with said join to use batch mode despite not using any columnstore indexes. When I do this, I have been regularly finding the following behaviour in the queries that previously did not use batch mode:

The parts of the execution plans that now use batch mode run much faster. In particular, window functions become incredible compared to what they were in the plans that had no batch mode parts.
The plans with batch mode parts will always have a much lower cost than the queries that do not, even when the they take longer to run.
Gather Streams sometimes becomes much slower, even though every operator is running evenly on two threads in the plans that have batch mode steps.
Queries that previously built a bitmap on one table in order to cheaply scan and then hash join another table by passing the bitmap's hash probe in the the scan become much slower. Instead of a bitmap inside an index scan, they have a very expensive Filter operator after the scan.

Is there any explanation for the final observation in my list? More importantly, how can I prevent the introduction of batch mode removing excellent bitmaps? That bold point is what I'm wanting answered here. If I could have both the bitmaps and the excellent benefits of batch mode elsewhere in the query (e.g. in the window functions), then my queries would be much faster. I accept that I could probably index the tables better, but I was already happy with the original hash joins.
Reproducible Example
Erik Darling quite rightly requested that I paste the plan, but I thought I'd go one better and give a reproducible example. The following uses the StackOverflow2010 database. You can load this in a docker container if you wish.
SET STATISTICS XML OFF;

USE StackOverflow2010;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #IDs;

SELECT TOP (10000)
  Id
INTO
  #IDs
FROM
  Comments;

ALTER TABLE #IDs ADD CONSTRAINT RowStorePK
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id);

SET STATISTICS XML ON;
  
;WITH [NumberedPosts] AS
(
  SELECT
    PostID
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PostID ORDER BY Score) RN
  FROM
    Comments
  WHERE
    PostID IN (SELECT Id FROM #IDs)
)
SELECT
  PostID
FROM
  NumberedPosts
WHERE
  RN = 1;

/*
  Hack to get batch mode for these queries despite 
  my real machine being on Standard Edition.
*/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX ColStoreNonClust ON #IDs (ID)
WHERE ID = 1 AND ID = 2;

-- Same query again.

;WITH [NumberedPosts] AS
(
  SELECT
    PostID
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PostID ORDER BY Score) RN
  FROM
    Comments
  WHERE
    PostID IN (SELECT Id FROM #IDs)
)
SELECT
  PostID
FROM
  NumberedPosts
WHERE
  RN = 1;

This plan is from before making the columnstore index. It uses a bitmap. This plan is from after making the columnstore index. It does not use a bitmap and runs much slower then the bitmap-using query.
I have seen this so many times that I've become convinced that it's a pattern that must have some general explanation or prevention steps.


how can I prevent the introduction of batch mode removing excellent bitmaps?

Short answer
You can't. You'll need to upgrade from Standard Edition.
Long answer
They might both be called bitmaps, but row-mode bitmaps are very different from batch mode bitmaps.
Batch mode bitmaps are only created by batch mode hash joins. They were originally implemented for use only with batch mode columnstore scans.
When mixed mode plans (containing both row- and batch mode operators) were added, specific support was included to evaluate the different batch mode bitmap structure in a row-mode Filter operator.
That support is minimally required to make things work at all. Optimizations such as pushing the filter down into the scan as a residual ('non-sarg') predicate, or even deeper into the storage engine, were simply not implemented.
They could have gone on to implement those optimizations, resulting in the sort of outcome you're looking for. In the event, they decided to invest the time and effort into creating Batch Mode on Rowstore (BMoR) instead.

Batch mode on rowstore enables batch mode execution for analytic workloads without requiring columnstore indexes. This feature supports batch mode execution and bitmap filters for on-disk heaps and B-tree indexes. Batch mode on rowstore enables support for all existing batch mode-enabled operators.

As briefly noted in the documentation above (emphasis added), BMoR allows the batch mode bitmap to be evaluated in a batch mode scan of a rowstore index. It provides many other general benefits besides that, of course.
Sadly, BMoR is a premium performance feature and not therefore available in Standard Edition.
If you use a batch mode hash join on Standard, you'll get a bitmap stuck in a Filter (unless the target is columnstore and accessed in batch mode).
If you use a row mode hash join, you'll get a different sort of bitmap that can be pushed deep into the storage engine (in limited circumstances).
You can't have the best of both worlds on Standard. You can either have a batch mode hash join and a stuck Filter or a row mode hash join and a bitmap that can be pushed down.
Compatibility level is not a factor, as mentioned in the question.
Caveat
None of the above means to suggest you cannot have batch mode in some parts of the plan and row mode in others. It is limited to the precise point about the behaviour of bitmaps associated with a hash join.
The optimizer is generally capable of choosing a plan with a row mode hash join plus bitmap while also running other operators like a Sort or Window Aggregate in batch mode. It's also quite capable of not doing what you want in any particular case. It's all subject to cost estimation and heuristics.
If you can generate the plan shape you want using supported methods, you may be able to force that plan using query store or plan guides. Best of luck with that, in general.

Technically possible, but uncommon
In your example, the optimizer is exceedingly unlikely to choose batch mode for the operators you want, while also choosing row mode for the hash join. The plan above is just to show it is a technically valid output from the optimizer. It was not generated using supported techniques.
Bitmap with merge join
The following tweaked demo query produces the bitmap you want with a merge join:
-- Hack empty CS index present on #IDs
WITH 
    NumberedPosts AS
    (
        SELECT
            C.PostId,
            rn = 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY C.PostId
                    ORDER BY C.Score) 
        FROM dbo.Comments AS C
        WHERE
            PostID IN 
            (
                SELECT 
                    Id + 0 - 0 
                FROM #IDs
            )
    )
SELECT
    NP.PostId
FROM NumberedPosts AS NP
WHERE
    NP.rn = 1
OPTION 
(
    MERGE JOIN
);


BMoR is not used. All operators above the merge join are batch mode. The very selective row mode filter is pushed down into the storage engine parallel scan of Comments.
